# What will happen when we create lock (Synchronized block) object inside a method?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, executorservice

```
public class SampleExecutorService {
    private static int count = 0;

    private void increment() {
        Object lock = new Object();
        synchronized (lock) {
            count++;
        }   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        SampleExecutorService obj = new SampleExecutorService();
        Runnable task = obj::increment;

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            executorService.submit(task);

        }
        executorService.shutdown();

        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("count : " + count);
    }
}
```

The expected result for the above program is 1000, but it not gives that result since I followed the synchronization mechanism.But it works fine if we create a lock object in class level instance variable. The right code snippet is below

```
public class SampleExecutorService {
    private static int count = 0;
    Object lock = new Object();
    private void increment() {
        //Object lock = new Object();
        synchronized (lock) {
            count++;
        }   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        SampleExecutorService obj = new SampleExecutorService();
        Runnable task = obj::increment;

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            executorService.submit(task);

        }
        executorService.shutdown();

        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("count : " + count);
    }
}
```

I want know, what will happen when we create lock object inside a method? what is the difference between lock object creation inside a method and as instance variable?

Comment: You're creating a new, separate lock object for each call, hence there's really no locking going on at all as each call locks on a *different* object. In effect, you'll have 10 threads concurrently modifying your counter without any kind of synchronization, leaving room for race conditions and visibility issues.

Comment: Every method call creates its own call stack so in the first example lock is meaningless.

Comment: Since you only create 1 instance of `SampleExecutorService`, the **difference is 1000 lock objects** (created inside method) **vs 1 lock object** (for the `SampleExecutorService` instance).

Comment: Thanks! I could able to understand your answers. It clears all my doubts regarding this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables are stored on thread stack and are created for each thread separately. If the local variable is not a primitive, then the instance itself is stored on the heap, but *the reference to object* is stored on the thread stack. That's why local variables are thread-safe.

Since the global variables are stored on the heap and are shared/visible by multiple threads they need to be synchronized.

So in your first example you are creating new lock for each thread, so multiple threads are still able to access it.

[Here's](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/java-memory-model.html) an excellent article on Java Memory Model

Comment: Thanks **@xagaffar**. but I have a doubt, objects inside a method are stored in heap(all objects are stored in heap) right?, Is my view correct?

Comment: @Rajeshkumar Technically yes, the object itself is stored in heap, but the local reference to object (which is what matters) is stored in thread stack. I'll update my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: __Thank you :-)__  **@xagaffar**. Your answer is very clear, helped me understand the concepts better. Article you shared looks well explained.